# If God is infinite and unchangeable how is there room for the universe?

Tags: theology, universe, infinity

If God is infinite and God cannot change, how is there room for the universe?, how could the universe come into existence?

UPDATE:

By "room" or "space" I did not necessarily mean physical space, because that would depend on how God is defined (whether physical, spiritual, etc). In order to go beyond the differing definitions about God, what I meant was "reality space". And even though I did not clarify this in the beginning, the question was mostly assumed to be referring to "reality space" rather than "physical space", in which case I should have asked:

If God is the infinite all encompassing unchanging ultimate reality, how did he make "reality space" for a new reality such as the universe to come into existence? Of course, at least assuming, if it has not been clearly demonstrated yet, that the universe is not everything that exists or can exist.

UPDATE 2:

I would definitely appreciate suggestions on how to further clarify my question so I can help others answer it.

Comment: I assume the theist will say that God is beyond(!) the universe. Hence both will not dispute someone's right to space.

Comment: Maybe God is the universe... See Spinoza.

Comment: A trajectory around a circular path is infinite and unchanging, and leaves plenty of room for the universe. I'm not sure if this addresses the question or not, but perhaps you need some positive claims about God - if only to distinguish him from a NASCAR course...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA -- the universe changes, so God == universe would contradict  a God who is unchanging.

Comment: One solution is that the universe exists and god doesn't.

Comment: @Dcleve - maybe the universe does not "change": there is a "global" space-time and from God's point of view all is "immediately present" because he is everywhere. Maybe...

Comment: +1 becasue several ppl seem to have tried asking this question, and you have done so *clearly*

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, our experienced data about the world might be illusions. For scientists, I treat this claim as one requiring MASIVE supporting justification, else it is just rejection of evidence in favor of a desired theory -- dogmatism.  That is how I treat Delusionism about consciousness, Block Time, and determinism about willing.  For God hypotheses, it is the same with an added down side.  Making God the Great Deceiver, who made a universe where we appeared to have freedom and wiling and time, but were deliberately deluded by God -- explicitly makes God's character pretty vile.

Comment: i think it would help to specific what relation you think there is between God and the world, except that one needs room for the other.

Comment: @user66697 -- indeed. The idea of all-knowing all-powerful omnipresent God leads to many paradoxes, not least of it is the problem of evil. That's why some Enlightenment thinkers, Leibniz in particular, toyed with the idea of God who, though a powerful entity, is not omnipotent and is itself a part of the Universe. Even the opening verses of John's Gospel can be interpreted this way by translating *logos* as "design/plan" (of a deterministic, therefore, Universe) -- "All things were made through it, and without it not a thing made that was made".

Answer (score 3):

This question does not really make any sense.

First of all, the phrase, "is infinite", can only be predicated of a quantity. God is not held to be a quantity, but a being. So, the phrase "God is infinite" does not really make sense. Instead, what theists have classically maintained about God is that God is infinitely powerful, infinitely knowledgeable, infinitely merciful, etc.

As for there being 'room' for the universe, theists do not typically claim that God is infinitely large in His physical dimensions. Rahther, they usually maintain that God does not exist inside of space-time, and therefore would not occupy any space or room.

Answer (score 1):

Most theists do not hold God to be infinite.  They instead hold that there are things that are part of God, and things that are not.  This solves the problem of a "space for the universe".

A God that is unchanging -- is the majority view among theists, and that DOES create a problem, as God is also taken as interactive.  An unchanging God is not subject to time.  The solution is to put God outside of time, and treat time as a local illusion within the greater illusion of our universe.  This leads to "block time", and determinism/predeterminism.  God interacting with the universe would then not be a change, as God's interaction would have been true forever as the "out of time" space God is in, is the real space of this world.

However, a significant minority of theists treat God as being IN time, and subject to change (and growth).  This is arguably the view of most of the authors of the Old Testament.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, but I wonder how you know that most theist do not consider God to be infinite?

Comment: @MarcoOcram -- nearly every Christian and Muslim theologian I have read holds that there are things in our universe that are not Godly.   As do multiple passages in the OT and Koran.   As the two most widely held theist religions, the theologians, plus non-theologian members reading the book texts, are reasonably inferred as representative of the majority view among theists.

Comment: Why does that imply that God is not infinite?

Comment: @MarcoOcram -- if there is a boundary between God and non-God then there are spaces that God does not extend into.  God is bounded, and does not extend everywhere.  This is definitional.

Comment: Why do you say that? I exist in space. Are you saying there is a boundary between me and space. Do I displace space? What can't I and God coexist in the same space?

Comment: @MarcoOcram -- it is logically possible for God to interpenetrate everything.  I am not arguing that to be logically impossible.  But the majority of theists say this is not the nature of God.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

Hegel says in his *Encyclopaedia* that Spinoza is often misunderstood as claiming that there is no God, i.e. that there is no *infinite*. But Hegel says this is a misconception: Spinoza claims that there is no world, i.e. there is no finitude. I think Hegel is right - and thus some people indeed agree with what you say, notably: genuine Spinozists.

Of course God is quite an abstract concept if we don't derive it from religious imagination, thus it's perhaps better to replace it with the notion of the *infinite*. You ask: How can there be *finitude* outside of something *infinite*?

If we consider these concepts mathematically, i.e. as, for example, infinite sequences, then there is nothing paradoxical about it. There might be two infinite nonoverlapping sets or two infinite sequences... or a finite sequence which isn't a subsequence of a given infinite sequence etc.

But Hegel would say that indeed the question you're asking isn't pointless because there is another sense of *infinite* which is the sense in which thought (or *The Concept*, as Hegel speaks of it) is *infinite* or *unbounded*, which means it's self-determining (Hegel uses various phrases to describe this notion, but it's good to understand it in terms of an ontological proof - in which a "mere" thought is enough to derive a fact about it or in terms of life which is self-perpetuating, has no goals outside of itself and also its being is its concept and its concept is its being - if that's too abstract: think of it in terms of genetic code of an animal being passed into its offspring). So: infinity is the unity of concept and being, in other words.

In this sense there is indeed a problem of seeing finitude as outside *infinity*... because there cannot really be any outside of *infinity* (think of thought againt... can there be something truly unthinkable?). But Hegel doesn't deny finitude like Spinoza, but rather says that is a moment within *infinity*. A thought, being infinite, can determine itself as being finite or, in other words, self-constrain itself. It's of course very abstract but it's an essential part of Hegel's critique of Kant who imagines thought (spontaneity) and finitude (receptivity) as juxtaposed, whereas Hegel sees receptivity as a moment of spontaneity. Other recognizably Hegelian insights can be derived form this notion - that's also why Hegel thinks that the ontological proof is, in fact, correct!

I know this might seem off-topic but it's an interesting notion in Hegel. I'm sure I wasn't exactly clear, but I hope it put some new light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a legitimate issue for anyone who believes in a perfect and eternal God. It may not seem like it on the surface, but it's a variant of the problem of evil--how could a perfect being create anything that even seems imperfect? And how could there be a specific moment of creation in the existence of a perfect and unchanging being?

One possible solution is as follows. First, we assume the panentheist universe, where the universe exists wholly within God, but God is more than the universe. Then we state that time is an illusion, and the the universe is perfect, it's just that we are unable to perceive it in its perfect and eternal wholeness.

This is admittedly not very satisfying, but I do think that when we start talking about the perfections of God we have to assume they won't be things we can wholly understand with a human intellect.

Comment: Or we can assume the the question is utter nonsense.

Comment: @MarcoOcram - Why? I thought it was an exceptionally good question.

Answer (score -1):

God is infinite in the way that space is infinite as in the way that he is not corporeal he has no real form he can be whatever he wants so he dosent take up any real space. I think of god as more of a thought and less of a real object because it's something that can contain infinite space but doesn't take up real mass, and god is unchanging because he never changes He still always truly and always truly will be god. So to answer you question he isn't really real in the sense of a touchable object and more like a thought that has infinite power.

Answer (score -1):

The universe is infinite. If anyone insists there is a finite boundary to space or time, he will have contrived an absurdity.

Interestingly there is no word meaning "ex nihilo creation" in any language. Ex nihilo is a purely contrived, imaginary and false concept.

The universe never came into existence, but the things in it did *in the original sense of the term*.

The word "exist" literally means "[to stand up or stand out](https://www.google.com/search?q=exist%20word%20origin&sca_esv=3cfb034d87db37ea&sxsrf=ACQVn0-_ItXHJPVIk5w8c3nWWNgHME8xKQ%3A1706819773840&source=hp&ei=vQC8ZfmRMPPbkPIP8OSfqAc&iflsig=ANes7DEAAAAAZbwOzTOUKpIxX9yy1bVr3KfixZvkpAVL&ved=0ahUKEwi55L-S_4qEAxXzLUQIHXDyB3UQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=exist%20word%20origin&gs_lp=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&sclient=gws-wiz)". It does not contrast sensibly with "absence of being" or any such notion. Nihilism is false. No concrete or material article ever came into being nor will any ever disappear into nothing.

God created in much the same way we do: [By intelligently organizing pre-existing materials](https://emp.byui.edu/jexj/new/talks/talks/JS%20KingFollettDiscourse.pdf).

The [conservation laws of physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_law) are true.

Comment: 'There is no word for ex nihilo creation in any language, ergo it is a contrived and false concept?!?!?!? There is no word for the Golden Gate Bridge, for the fourth hair from the left on my right eyebrow, for the fact that the waistband of  my boxer shorts has lost its elasticity- does that mean all those things are contrived and false concepts?

Comment: @MarcoOcram I did not say "ergo". These are independent witnesses: the absurdity of violating known physical laws on the one hand, and the utter lack of any historical linguistic conceptualization for a nonsensical idea on the other.

Comment: There is an utter lack of historic linguistic conceptualisation for the term smart TV, but such things exist, so the point you are making is irrelevant.

Comment: @MarcoOcram Ex nihilo is not a technological innovation. It is not a product made from parts. It is not a realizable thing in any sense. It is literally an idea conveying a universal, trans-existential claim regarding the foundations of the physical universe without analogue anywhere in literature or reality. As such it ought to be expected that, if it were a concept attributable to Scripture or a bona fide element of history as old as the Earth itself, then the Father of language ought to have planted that word somewhere in the vocabularies of His children, but He didn't, and that is telling.

Comment: You are talking nonsense yet again. You claim an important test of the validity of an idea is whether historically a single word has been coined to refer to it!!! What about Newton's First Law, The Solar System, Anselm's ontological argument, caveat emptor, modus ponens, and countless other widely accepted ideas for which a single word has never been coined?

Comment: @MarcoOcram Not coined. Anyone can make something up. Original. There is no original word in any language meaning "ex nihilo creation". If we confuse modern inventions for what was originally there in language we are confusing the authorship of men with the Authorship of God. The distinction is vital and inherently meaningful. It has already been demonstrated that the first action verb that occurs in our Holy Writ does not mean what mainstream modern persons claim it means. It never did.

Comment: @MarcoOcram As I already said, one can construct legitimate concepts using compatible building blocks of language. One cannot however retroactively impute a non-native meaning on an original word using an interpretation that did not exist before. That is ex post facto pleading and presentism. The language already exists describing Creation and it is not ex nihilo anywhere.

Comment: You continue to talk nonsense.  Language mutates. New ideas emerge and are legitimately formulated in terms of old words. You are scraping the bottom of the barrel of misguided arguments in either a desperate or irrational attempt to avoid the thrust of my criticism.

Comment: @MarcoOcram Of course it mutates, through ignorance, deception and dissembling. That doesn't make the mutated concepts true or even make sense. Huge proportions of language are bastardized (illegitimate). The word "create" never meant ex nihilo until some credalists decided they would rewrite the Scriptures and where they couldn't rewrite, they changed the language instead. Doesn't make it valid. Evolution is a false theory. Authoritatively there is no such thing as ex nihilo. Again, you can prioritize made-up fantasies over the truths of God, but that doesn't make your ideas right.

Comment: @MarcoOcram Pardon me while I go make up some words to prove I'm right

Comment: Well said! Have a lovely weekend!

Comment: @MarcoOcram You as well!